# Why does this code plot by day of the week?

Tags: r, plot

Link to the data set which is a date and time column along with electricity usage columns
https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/exdata%2Fdata%2Fhousehold_power_consumption.zip

```
 power1 <- read.csv(file = "c:/datasets/household_power_consumption.txt", stringsAsFactors=F, header = TRUE,
               sep=";", dec = ".", na.strings="?", col.names = c("date1","time1","Global_active_power", "Global_reactive_power",
                                                                 "Voltage","Global_intensity","Sub_metering_1","Sub_metering_2",
                                                                 "Sub_metering_3")) 

power1$date1 <- as.Date(power1$date1, format="%d/%m/%Y")

power2 <- subset(power1, subset=(date1  >= "2007-02-01" & date1 <= "2007-02-02"))

datetime1 <- paste(as.Date(power2$date1), power2$time1)

power2$Datetime <- as.POSIXct(datetime1)

plot(power2$Global_active_power~power2$Datetime, type="l", ylab="Global Active Power (kilowatts)", xlab="")
```

When I run the above, I get the graph like I'm supposed to with the days of the week on the x axis even when I run summary, head and str() I don't see anything in the data about days of the week.

I tried to add my own day column with mutate but it didn't work.

And it didn't work when I subset it like the following. It subset properly where I had only the data I needed, but it wouldn't plot with the date1 column or the day of the week column I created via mutate

```
power2 <- subset(power1, subset=(as.Date(date1,  format = "%d/%m/%Y") >= "2007-02-01" 
                             & as.Date(date1,  format = "%d/%m/%Y") <= "2007-02-02"))
```

I know that as.Posixct will have all the metadata in there, but I don't understand why is it when I combine the date and time columns into it's own column only then it plots by day of the week [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWhPB.png)without me asking.

When I run it like this, the combined date and time column data is corrupted with the wrong year

```
power11 <- read.csv(file = "c:/datasets/household_power_consumption.txt", stringsAsFactors=F, header = TRUE,
                sep=";", dec = ".", col.names = c("date1","time1","Global_active_power", "Global_reactive_power",
                                       "Voltage","Global_intensity","Sub_metering_1","Sub_metering_2",
                                       "Sub_metering_3")) 
                #colClasses = c("Date", "character", "factor", "numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric"))
power22 <- subset(power11, subset=(as.Date(date1,  format = "%d/%m/%Y") >= "2007-02-01" 
                             & as.Date(date1,  format = "%d/%m/%Y") <= "2007-02-02"))
datetime1 <- paste(as.Date(power22$date1), power22$time1)
power22$Datetime <- as.POSIXct(datetime1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link would be helpful:
http://earlh.com/blog/2009/07/07/plotting-with-custom-x-axis-labels-in-r-part-5-in-a-series/

add an argument to your plot() call: xaxt='n'

```
plot(power2$Global_active_power~power2$Datetime, type="l", ylab="Global Active Power (kilowatts)", xlab="", xaxt='n')
```

that tells plot not to add x-axis labels. Then add an axis() call:

```
axis(side=1, at=power22$Datetime, labels=format(power22$Datetime, '%b-%y'))
```

I used '%b-%y' here, because that's what I saw on the site I referenced, but you would want to use the format code appropriate to your needs.

Comment: Thank you, but I was looking for a why it works the way it does. If I run the first batch of code in this exact order I get the answer I need. But if I run it in a different order like say import the file, subset, and create the new column when date1 and time1 are still character columns then the new datetime1 column has corrupted years or 0001 instead of 2007. If I change date1 to a date and then create the column then it's OK. It doesn't work even if I run the plot with as.POSIXct and as.Date. Only if the date is changed before the plot is run.